# I have outlook 2016 but i cant search nothing in a shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, find

I have outlook 2016 but i cant search nothing in a shared mailbox i tried to create a mailbox and disable cached mode but the problem persist. Not find nothing In shared mailbox .

Comment: "I can't search nothing". Could you please explain what you mean by this? Are you trying to search for the word "nothing" or is this an attempted colloqualism? Also, please use the EDIT button to add punctuation to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you search primary mailbox normally?

How do you open the shared mailbox in Outlook?

Normally, shared folders can only be searched via current folder scope.

According to my research, if the shared mailbox is added via the Exchange email account’s Advanced tab (using the Open these additional mailboxes option) or via Auto-Mapping, there are some limitation when you are using Outlook Search option.

Please refer to the details in the following similar thread from TechNet forum:

[Search in Outlook shared Mailbox does not work](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b29e7f44-00ac-42a8-932f-aa67dabb0e5b/search-in-outlook-shared-mailbox-does-not-work?forum=outlook)

[Understanding Search Scopes in Microsoft Outlook](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Global-Customer-Service/Understanding-Search-Scopes-in-Microsoft-Outlook/ba-p/428841)